# Extract 2bytes (u_short) from pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers

I have a pointer and I want to assign the bytes from x to (x+1) to a unsigned short. I was hoping that I could just

```
(unsigned short) pointer[x]
```

but the first byte seems to always be empty. But when I check the value of bytes x and x+1 individually the data is there.

Where have I noobed? (I just made it a verb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned short i = (pointer[x] << 8) + pointer[x+1]
```

Assuming you want x to be the high bits and x+1 to be the low bits.  Actually, you should keep endianness in mind here too.

EDIT:

This may also work:

```
*(unsigned short *) pointer[x]
```

However, this will be affected by endianness, for example, in little endian the first byte will be the lower 8 bits, while x+1 will be the higher bytes.

Comment: @Matthew: You can also cast the pointer to a unsigned short pointer and then dereference it.

Comment: Also looks like order of operations may be ambiguous without (pointer[x] << 8) + pointer[x+1]

Comment: @Matthew: You are right I should have had the brackets, I fixed that

Comment: Thanks for the second example. Reading up on this technique since it causes my app to crash for some reason.

Comment: @Matthew:  That's odd.  I've used the second method before without any problems.

Comment: I am certainly doing something wrong. I will read up so I can apply it to my use. Thanks again :)